# Determinant of A + I

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let **A** be an $n\times n$ matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n$, and $I_n$ is a $n\times n$ identity matrix.

How can I show $|I_n\pm A|=\prod_{i=1}^n (1\pm \lambda_i)$?

Comment: Welcome to Math. SE @Ivy, can you show your attempts for to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.

Given
$$Av_i = \lambda_i v_i$$

Find the eigenvalues
$$(A + I)v_i = \text{???}$$